# Обеспечение целостности даных

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, dbase

Есть таблица с компаниями, каждая компания может поставщиком какого-то продукта другой компании (с этой же таблицы). Надо как-то сохранять какая компания является поставщиком, какая клиентом. Бывает ситуация, что компания А является клиентом Б по одному товару, и в тот же момент компания Б является клиентом компании А  по другому товару. Как можно реализовать такую архитектуру без костылей в 3НФ без потери целостности данных? СУБД: Postgresql.

Comment: Обычная таблица связей, в чём подвох? Табличка: поставщик, клиент, продукт. PK на все три поля, FK на соответствующие таблички.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте три таблицы:

- Компании
- Товары
- Поставки

В третей таблице заносите связи, типа:

```
id_provider INTEGER, -- ид поставщика из "Компании"
id_consumer INTEGER, -- ид потребителя из "Компании"
id_goods INTEGER -- ид товара из "Товары"
```

Избыточности - нуль, достаточность - 100%.

Comment: а ключ делать по 3 полям?

Comment: Я бы сделал несколько ключей. Пример: "Найти всех поставщиков", "Найти всех потребителей", "Найти движение товара" ... - это уже минимум три ключа.

Comment: спасибо, вопрос закрыт

Comment: Есть маленькая проблема (сори, если это елементарщина). Как вывести в паралельных столбцах имя поставщика и имя клиента? Я забыл об этом сказать изначально, а это главное условие.

Comment: селект по "Поставкам" + left join по "поставщикам"+left join по "потребителям". Наверняка в таблице "поставки" должна быть дата поставки. Тогда + where дата поставки beetwen диапазон дат.